# Parent key not found and I'm not sure why

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, spring-jdbc

This is the error that I am getting! This is when I try to update some values in my sql MY_TABLE table! Ignore spellings! integrity constraint from what I see elsewhere is that I am trying to input a value that is not present in the parent table! I am just not sure which value that is!

```
integrity constraint (MY.FK_MY_TABLE) violated - parent key not found
; nested exception is java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (MY.FK_MY_TABLE) violated - parent key not found
```

```
@Component
public class JdbcTemplates {

    private JdbcTemplate insertTemplate;

    @Value("${TS_ID}")
    private String someId;

    private static final String INSERT_QUERY = "INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (CFN_NO,CS_D,SOME_CONSTANT," +
            "A_NO,R_NO,B_NAME,O_ID,C_ID,A_TYPE,B_STATUS,R_PAGE,R_DATETIME," +
            "T_S_RESULTS,D_CNT,B_ACCT_NO,ACC_TYPE,A_F_ID,A_C_ID,AP_ID) " +
            "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,SYS_DATE,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    @Resource(name = "dataSource")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        this.insertTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(this.dataSource);
    }

    public void insertActivity(final String cnfNumber, final Act act){

        insertActivityTemplate.update(INSERT_QUERY, new PreparedStatementSetter() {

            @Override
            public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
                ps.setString(1, cnfNumber);
                ps.setString(2, act.getCSId());
                ps.setString(3, DAOConstants.SOME_CONSTANT);
                ps.setString(4, act.getAccNumber());
                ps.setString(5, act.getRNumber());
                ps.setString(6, act.getBName());
                ps.setString(7, act.getOId());
                ps.setString(8, act.getCId());
                ps.setString(9, activity.getAType().getTCode());
                ps.setString(10, YesNo.NO.getSLabel());
                ps.setInt(11, act.getRPage());
                ps.setInt(12, act.getTResults());
                ps.setInt(13, act.getDDataCount());
                ps.setString(14, act.getBNumber());
                ps.setString(15, act.getAType());
                ps.setString(16, act.getAId());
                ps.setString(17, act.getAId());
                ps.setString(18, tSId);
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Which field is the FK? You should check if the FK you are trying to add exists in the referenced table.

Comment: FK i believe just means Foreign Key! Not associated with any value

Comment: This constraint error means you're trying to add a Foreign Key but the value doesn't exist in the referenced table.

Comment: Is there a way to tell which one is the Foreign Key! fairly new to SQL and JDBC

Comment: Did you create those tables? If yes, would you have the scripts you used to do so?

Comment: `ORA-02291` suggests this is Oracle, not MySQL.

Comment: Fair! thanks @RKrum Unfortunately I didn't...

Comment: In this case I suggest you check on how to visualize table structures and foreign keys in the database tool of your preference so you can troubleshoot your issue. We know that one of the FKs doesn't exist in the table, you just need to identify which one it is.

Comment: ok thanks.. I'll look into it!

Comment: I fixed the issue! you were right! Thanks !

Comment: I just had mismatching values for items which were hardcoded into the oracle sql...like C_ID and CS_ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have sorted it out in your code, but next time you run into this problem in an Oracle database you can find out the answer from the data dictionary.

Go to the error message:

> ORA-02291: integrity constraint (MY.FK_MY_TABLE) violated - parent key
>   not found

Get the constraint owner and name from within the parens, `MY.FK_MY_TABLE` and then look it up in the data dictionary.

Log into the database using the same credentials your app uses.

```
select * from all_cons_columns where owner = 'MY' and CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'FK_MY_TABLE'
```

This should show you the table name and column(s) that are causing your distress.

There is an `all_constraints` view as well, but that won't tell you the column name.

Comment: Thanks much! I'm sure this will be helpful in the near future if I deal with Oracle sql.